# SharePoint Online site and URL naming

Tags: sharepoint-online, hub-site

For our upcoming intranet based on SharePoint Online, we need to develop a site naming strategy. I'd really appreciate comments on the below questions.

1. Long before starting the Intranet project, our users have created vast amounts of sites under acme.sharepoint.com/sites, which likely will cause naming collision for our upcoming intranet sites. For example, we'll likely run into wanting to creates /sites/siteA for our intranet, but finding that this site already exist. So we could use some unique namespace for our intranet sites. How have other sharepoint companies solved this - have you for example prefixed each intranet site with something (say /sites/i_siteA), or have you put your intranet sites somewhere other than /sites (if this is even possible), or have you done something else?
2. Creating and renaming site URLs in itself is trivial, but hub sites are worse as changing the URLs of those isn't supported. So we need to be very careful creating and sticking to a hub site naming strategy (in particular the URL to such sites). One option would be to add for example "hub" or "portal" to all hub sites. Which route have other companies gone - have your hub sites had "hub" or something appended to the site name (and thus the URL)?
3. This is related to the above question: Does you URLs indicate whether a site is a hub site? Does the URLs indicate if a site is a company function site such as HR hub, or if it's a site for company facing department information? What is you create a communication site for department A, but later on decide to convert it to a hub site - do you rename the URL before converting to hub site?

Answer (score 1):

For Planning hub site, first it may be better for you to read this [official introduction](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/planning-hub-sites) to get some idea of it.

And for you question, I will recommend you to only grant the permission of creating new sites to certain number of admins. Allow end users to create new site collections will always cause a mess.

A meaningful URL is always welcomed, same for a hub site which is a portal to most of the users. "Hub" or "Portal" is fine. Still that is not a necessary thing as there is no need to make all the end users understand the meaning of hub sites.

Comment: Thanks for your input, and link to the official documentation. When it comes to creating new sites, we actually do have an automated process which ensures consistent naming and such, but very many sites (with non-standardized names and URLs) were created before this process was implemented.